# Email header: last 'received: from' header IP is 127.0.0.1

Tags: spam, email-headers, postfix-mta

Have a question about the structure of email headers.

I've been analyzing spam sent through my Postfix MTA, and have noticed a small amount (< 5%) have the localhost address 127.0.0.1 as the final 'received: from header'.

The 2nd-to-last header shows the IP of the spam mail server.

I'm assuming that the spammer is relaying through an MTA on his local box to a remote server, and that's why the last received header (which represents the first in the sending chain) is showing the localhost IP.

I have an example below of an actual header with my servers info changed for privacy (spammer's is real).

Just wanted confirmation that my assumption is correct on this.

```
    Return-Path: <ProsventUltraBlend@operantish.com>
Delivered-To: acme2@mx.acme.net
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mx.acme.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id XXXXXXXXX
    for <me@acme.net>; Thu, 30 Mar 2017 16:08:16 -0400 (EDT)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mydomain = acme.com
Received: from mx.acme.net ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mx.acme.net [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id XXXXXXXX for <me@acme.net>;
    Thu, 30 Mar 2017 16:08:15 -0400 (EDT)
Received: from layrbc.operantish.com (layrbc.operantish.com [66.118.137.94])
    by mx.acme.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0A576D1FAE8
    for <me@acme.net>; Thu, 30 Mar 2017 16:08:14 -0400 (EDT)
Received: from 025a1bf3.layrbc.operantish.com ([127.0.0.1]:19719 helo=layrbc.operantish.com)
    by layrbc.operantish.com with ESMTP id 02DYCACOHN5A1BOPBVDGQKF3;
    for <me@acme.net>; Thu, 30 Mar 2017 13:08:13 -0700
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 13:08:13 -0700
```

Answer (score 0):

I know hardly any more than Jon Snow, but I do know that 127.0.0.1 can appear in mail headers. I.e. when a spam filter takes the mail, checks it and sends it on it's way.